# How to Dynamically Create <option> elements within a parent <optgroup>

Tags: javascript, jquery, optgroup

I am trying to dynamically generate a structure similar to

```
 <select>
     <optgroup>
         <options> option 1 </option>
          <options> option 2 </option>
                   etc..
      </optgroup>
 </select>
```

using the following code.  As you can see from the debug screen I can't seem to get the options embedded within the `<optgroup>`.   Can anyone help please?

```
    milestoneData =[{"phase_ID":21,"phase_name":"hello1"}, {"phase_ID":22,"phase_name":"hello2"}]
    var optionGroup = document.createElement("optgroup");
    optionGroup.setAttribute("label","Project 1");
    optionGroup.setAttribute("value","100");
    $(".test").append(optionGroup).attr("id","theid");
    for (var i = 0; i <  milestoneData.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute("value",milestoneData[i].phase_ID);
        option.innerHTML=milestoneData[i].phase_name;
        $('#theid').append(option);
   }
```

HTML anchor is `<select id = "testid" name = "testing" class ="test" >`

[image: render produced by above code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, the problem you currently have its at `$(".test").append(optionGroup).attr("id","theid");`

You currently are saying append `optionGroup` to `.test` and add `id` to `.test` element, which in your case you should add the `id` to `optionGroup`

So it would be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   milestoneData =[{"phase_ID":21,"phase_name":"hello1"}, {"phase_ID":22,"phase_name":"hello2"}]

    var optionGroup = document.createElement("optgroup");
    optionGroup.setAttribute("label","Project 1");
    optionGroup.setAttribute("value","100");
    optionGroup.setAttribute("id","theid");

    $(".test").append(optionGroup);

   for (var i = 0; i <  milestoneData.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute("value",milestoneData[i].phase_ID);
        option.innerHTML=milestoneData[i].phase_name;

        $('#theid').append(option);
   }
});
```

I've created a quick jsfiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/gcpn10kd/1/

You can check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) some examples how `optgroup` should be structured

Comment: But isn't he appending the option directly to #theid (the select)? He should append to the option group.

Comment: @Phiter yeah, that's why I added the id to the option group so the appending should go to the option group.

Comment: Oh I see. I thought `#theid` was the select.

Comment: Perfect.   They say not to say thanks here but heck I have to.  After nearly 5 hours trying to fix it.   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set id to optgroup like `<optgroup id="optgroupID">`

In JS: (assume that we are adding 3 more options)

```
   var id = document.getElementById("optgroupID");  
   var value = document.getElementById("optgroupID").innerHTML;  
   for(var i=0;i<3;i++){  
      value += "<option>"+i+"</option>";  
   }  
   id.innerHTML = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Alexander, you need to append option with optgroup, then optgroup group will be append to select. See the solution

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var milestoneData =[{"phase_ID":21,"phase_name":"hello1"}, {"phase_ID":22,"phase_name":"hello2"}]
    var optionGroup = document.createElement("optgroup");
    optionGroup.setAttribute("label","Project 1");
    optionGroup.setAttribute("value","100");
    $(".test").append(optionGroup).attr("id","theid");
    for (var i = 0; i <  milestoneData.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute("value",milestoneData[i].phase_ID);
        option.innerHTML=milestoneData[i].phase_name;
        optionGroup.append(option);
       
   }
    $('#theid').append(optionGroup);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id = "testid" name = "testing" class ="test" ></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up jQuery with vanilla javascript. I'd recommend using jQuery entirely if you're going to use that in your site.

You could benefit from a smaller code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var milestoneData = [{ "phase_ID": 21, "phase_name": "hello1" }, { "phase_ID": 22, "phase_name": "hello2" }];

  var optionGroup = $("<optgroup/>", {
    label: 'Project 1',
    value: '100'
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < milestoneData.length; i++) {
    var option = $("<option/>", {
      value: milestoneData[i].phase_ID,
      text: milestoneData[i].phase_name
    });

    optionGroup.append(option);
  }
  $(".test").append(optionGroup);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="test">

</select>
```

Comment: As you can see, you don't really need an ID for the option group.

Comment: Yes thanks for that.  That was indeed something I did want to address.